# How to Apply the SSIM Measure on RGB Images?

Tags: image-processing, perceived-quality

I want to compare the [similarity of two images by looking at its structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) and colors. I need a measure that takes both structural and color fidelity into account. When I checked the formulation of original paper, it is said only x and y mean and variance is measured. Does SSIM account for structure only or does it take color similarity into account too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What usually can be done is calculate it per channel and have the average (Or weighted average).

So if you have $ {R}_{1}, {G}_{1}, {B}_{1} $ and $ {R}_{2}, {G}_{2}, {B}_{2} $ you would do:

$$ {SSIM}_{r} \left( {R}_{1}, {R}_{2} \right), {SSIM}_{g} \left( {G}_{1}, {G}_{2} \right), {SSIM}_{b} \left( {B}_{1}, {B}_{2} \right) $$

Then $ {SSIM}_{rgb} = {w}_{r} {SSIM}_{r} + {w}_{g} {SSIM}_{g} + {w}_{b} {SSIM}_{b} $.

For instance, MATLAB's `ssim()` does the above with $ {w}_{r} = {w}_{g} = {w}_{b} = \frac{1}{3} $.

SciKit Image's `compare_ssim()` also apply it channel wise using the `multichannel` flag:

[image]

Comment: I just made a 512*512 all orange jpeg and the same size yellow jpeg file. Then I measured the similarity by using SSIM and result is 0.60.  Then I made a red one and the similarity between orange and red is 0.8. It compares colors too I suppose. At first when I checked the name, because there is "Structural", it only measured structure of the images but my little experiment shows that it measures colors too. Do you confirm this?

Comment: Do you really need to separate the image into its RGB components to get the exact similarity? Can't I use the original image and the image to be measured directly without separating into 3 components?

Comment: By design it only applied to a single channel image. What do you use to apply the comparison? If you use MATLAB, what it does is exactly as above with $ {w}_{r} = {w}_{g} = {w}_{b} = \frac{1}{3} $.

Comment: You don't need to separate as in 3 different arrays, just implement it in such way.

Comment: I use Scikit image in Python. https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/metrics/_structural_similarity.py  There is a "multichannel" argument there. If I use it I hope I do  not have to measure channels separately.

Comment: @Lyrk, You asked how to implement this. Both SciKit Image and MATLAB apply it as I wrote above with uniform weights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124303/discussion-between-lyrk-and-royi).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a commonly used standard when implementing it; the original paper [1] and reference code [2] only provide the definition for grayscale images.

This means the SSIM result for color images may vary from implementation to implementation. The $\frac{1}{3}SSIM_R + \frac{1}{3}SSIM_G + \frac{1}{3} SSIM_B$ answer @Royi gives is how ImageQualityIndexes.jl (Julia version) is implemented.

As for MATLAB's built-in `ssim()` function, it treats the RGB image as 3D volumic data instead of three independent 2D slices. This is quite different because SSIM internally applies a few filters. If it is 3D volumic data, the filter kernel is 3D, and if it is 2D slices, then the filter kernel is still 2D.

> `edit ssim` in MATLAB and you'll notice this note
>
> A and REF can be arrays of up to three dimensions. All 3D arrays
> are considered 3D volumetric images. RGB images will also be
> processed as 3D volumetric images.

Unconditionally treating N-dimensional RGB images as N+1 dimensional gray images is not a good idea because

1. filtering a length-3 dimension almost certainly introduces artifacts due to the padding strategy. For instance, SSIM by default applies a gaussian kernel of size 11, and thus the image is padded to at least size `(h+10, w+10, 3+10)` before applying the filter.
2. the channel contains quite different information from height/width, and if you try to mix them together, you usually don't get a good result.

This is why ImageQualityIndexes.jl deliberately diverges from MATLAB's numeric results.

---

To simply verify that MATLAB uses 3D volumic definition and ImageQualityIndexes use the mean of channelwise SSIM definition, I use the ["peppers_color"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaImages/TestImages.jl/images/images/peppers_color.tif) and ["mandrill"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaImages/TestImages.jl/images/images/mandrill.tiff) color image from [TestImages.jl](https://github.com/JuliaImages/TestImages.jl).

```
% MATLAB
img1 = imread("peppers_color.tif");
img2 = imread("mandrill.tiff");

% weighted sum of the channelwise ssim
ssim_r = ssim(img1(:,:,1), img2(:,:,1)) % 0.1468
ssim_g = ssim(img1(:,:,2), img2(:,:,2)) % 0.1037
ssim_b = ssim(img1(:,:,3), img2(:,:,3)) % 0.0911
wssim = 1/3 * (ssim_r + ssim_g + ssim_b) % 0.1139

% MATLAB's built-in ssim
ssim(img1, img2) % 0.1219
```

```
# julia
using ImageQualityIndexes, TestImages
img1 = testimage("peppers_color")
img2 = testimage("mandrill")
assess_ssim(img1, img2) # 0.11387
```

References:

- [1] Wang, Z., Bovik, A. C., Sheikh, H. R., & Simoncelli, E. P. (2004). Image quality assessment: from error visibility to structural similarity. *IEEE transactions on image processing*, 13(4), 600-612.
- [2] Wang, Z., Bovik, A. C., Sheikh, H. R., & Simoncelli, E. P. (2003). The SSIM Index for Image Quality Assessment. Retrived May 30, 2019, from [http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/%7Elcv/ssim/)

Answer (score -1):

It's not indicated for colors, it only accounts for Structure. You could check more info on this paper [Understanding SSIM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.13846.pdf).

An alternative presented by the original authors on the paper [Video Quality Assessment Based on Structural
Distortion Measurement](https://live.ece.utexas.edu/publications/2004/zwang_vssim_spim_2004.pdf) is to take a weighted average of SSIM results per channel on the YCrCb space like $SSIM_{final} = 0.8 \times SSIM_y + 0.1 \times SSIM_{Cr} + 0.1 \times SSIM_{Cb}$.

Comment: I just checked SSIM between two images which are same size and single color. SSIM is 1 for same color images. Differs when colors are far. So this shows color is taken into account. I think you are mistaken.

Comment: SSIM does not compare colors, what you're doing is to compare 3 different images, one for each channel; in which the algorithm evaluates structure, luminance, and contrast information with a reference image.